# How to get the cell count matching the value and color of the active from CountIF, and loop code equal to cell count found from CountIF in VBA Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I have another question of similar nature of my resent questions. I have a function in VBA that finds cells matching the date and cell color of the active cell, after it finds the next matching cell, it goes to corresponding cell in Column H, and highlights it Cyan. This works just what I want it, but I have to click the run macro every time. I want the function to work on all matching cells. I am thinking on using a Do Until loop, found @ http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/do-until-loop.html, but to do this I need to know the number of matching cells to make the loop stop.

My working code:

```
Sub Test1()
'
' Test1 Macro
'
'
Dim CellColor As Variant
Dim SearchDate As String, FoundAt As String


CellColor = Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).Interior.Color
SearchDate = Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).NumberFormat

    Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
    Application.FindFormat.Clear
    Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = SearchDate
    Application.FindFormat.Interior.Color = CellColor

    Cells.Find(What:="", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=True).Activate

End Sub
```

The loop code I am thinking on using found in the link above:

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 1

Do Until i > 6
    Cells(i, 1).Value = 20
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

I have this code of CountIF:

```
Dim cellCount As Integer
cellCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B1:B30"), "7/22/2016") ‘Count matching 

MsgBox cellCount ‘test to see if count works
```

But there are two problems wrong with it. Problem One, I have to manually enter the date “7/22/2016” into the code instead of using the variable “SearchDate.” Problem Two is that it only searches for the date, and not the cell color that filters the dates in my spreadsheet.

So my question is in all of this. How do I get the count of number of dates meeting the date and color value of the active cell, and carry that number over to a variable to be used in a loop?

If there is a more efficient way to do all of this, please tell me. Many thanks in advance!!!

Reference pictures:

[Screenshot showing the spreadsheet of dates and colors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPN6n.jpg)

Comment: if i have understood your question then in the screenshot provided a match of B4 is found in B8 and B13. therefore H8 and H13 should be highlighted in Cyan. Is that what you want ?

Comment: Sorta,  I want to find the cell count of the active cell. So if B4 is the active cell,  I want to find the count of cells that equal to activate cell. In this case the count is 3.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly then this is what you will be looking for

```
Sub Test1()

Dim CellColor As Variant
Dim SearchDate As String

For i = 1 To 19
    CellColor = Cells(i, 2).Interior.Color
    SearchDate = Cells(i, 2).NumberFormat

    If Cells(i, 2).Value <> "" Then
        For j = i To 19
            If i <> j And CellColor = Cells(j, 2).Interior.Color And SearchDate = Cells(j, 2).NumberFormat Then
                Cells(j, 8).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 255)
            End If
        Next j
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I will give this a try when I can. I am curious where the 19 comes from.

Comment: just a random number, choose 19 as 19 rows were visible in your screenshot

Comment: Ahh, Makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The next function will count all the matching cells in column B. 
It does not highlight any cell. You will have to add this part on your own.

in order to use it simply add the following in your code:

```
Dim x As Integer
x = countMatchingCells
```

function:

```
Function countMatchingCells() As Integer

Dim CellColor As Variant
Dim SearchDate As String, FoundAt As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim counter As Integer

CellColor = Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).Interior.Color
SearchDate = Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).NumberFormat
counter = 0
'assuming we are working on sheet1:
For i = 1 To Sheets(1).Cells(Sheets(1).Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
If Cells(i, 2).Interior.Color = CellColor And _
Cells(i, 2).NumberFormat = SearchDate Then
countMatchingCells = countMatchingCells + 1
'you can write more code here, for example if you want to highlight cells once you found a match
End If
Next i
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a try when I get the chance.